# neo4j datetime wrong translation to 1970

Tags: datetime, neo4j, utc

I have nodes with datetime and when using conversion as:
https://community.neo4j.com/t/cannot-construct-date-time-from-no-value-failure-when-processing-file/34973/3
https://community.neo4j.com/t/cannot-construct-date-time-from-no-value-failure-when-processing-file/34973/4

I got wrong dates to 1970. Can you help find what is wrong with this query ?

```
MATCH (n:Resource) 
with n, datetime({epochmillis: toInteger(n.created_at)}) as time
return n.created_at, toInteger(n.created_at), time
```

Results of time column does not make sense, they should be in 2022.
https://www.epochconverter.com/

Got this result:

```
"n.created_at"   │"toInteger(n.created_at)"│"time"                          │
╞═════════════════╪═════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│1651750310.706613│1651750310               │"1970-01-20T02:49:10.310000000Z"│
├─────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│1651750359.453425│1651750359               │"1970-01-20T02:49:10.359000000Z"│
├─────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│1651751391.714048│1651751391               │"1970-01-20T02:49:11.391000000Z"│
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `epochmillis` which expect to get the timestamp in milliseconds, but your `created_at` is in seconds. Just multiply it by 1000 before inserting to `epochmillis`